# ROW_NUMBER() window_agg rows estimation

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

PostgreSQL 9.4

Consider the following pretty simlpe query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3, col4 ORDER BY date DESC NULLS LAST) rn
    FROM tbl) sub WHERE rn = 2123231
```

The analyzed plan is

```
                HERE
------------------------------------------------->
                                                 |
                                                 |
Subquery Scan on sub  (cost=0.42..23380.71 rows=1216 width=40) (actual time=269.947..269.947 rows=0 loops=1)
  Filter: (sub.rn = 2123231)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 243147
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.42..20340.47 rows=243219 width=32) (actual time=7.361..248.437 rows=243147 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using idx on tbl  (cost=0.42..14260.00 rows=243219 width=32) (actual time=0.014..66.079 rows=243147 loops=1)
```

My question is how the total rows  `1216` is computed. Is there any strictly defined rule for that?